# I operated on the name of the array and didn't get error or warnings why?

Tags: c, free, dynamic-arrays

I wrote a code expecting to receive error along with the description expression must be a modifiable value but i didn't, I don't understand can arrays that were dynamically allocated be modified?

```
{
    int* x;
    x =(int*) malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    if (x == 0)
    {
        printf("sorry met an error");
        exit(1);
    }
    x[0] = 0;
    x[1] = 1;
    x[2] = 2;
    printf("%p\n", x);
    printf("%d\n", x[0]);
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(x));
    x++;
    printf("%p\n", x);
    printf("%d\n", x[0]);
    printf("%d\n", x[1]);
    printf("%d", sizeof(x));
    free(x);
    return 0;
}
```

By the way the free function here is also triggering a breakpoint any ideas why?

Comment: You don't have an actual array. `x` is a pointer which points to something that can be treated as an array but it is not an array.

Comment: `malloc()` returns a pointer to an allocated block of memory (in your case big enough to hold three `int` values). There is no array involved at all. You are simply using a postfix expression `address[offset]` to access each of those `int` values. Using post-increment `++` on your pointer simply advances the pointer by `sizeof(one int)` value.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think you are being extra pedantic here. From the non-compiler writer’s POV, I think it fair to consider that those three `int`s constitute a dynamically-allocated array, accessible through the pointer `x`.

Comment: You cannot afford to call `free(x)` because you did `x++;` in the middle of the code.  The value passed to `free()` must have be returned by `malloc()` (or `realloc()` or  `calloc()`, etc).  You could  call `free(x - 1);` to pass the original pointer to `free()`.

Comment: When you are loose with the term `"array"`, people start thinking they can do `sizeof (array)` to get its size (as we see with `printf("%d", sizeof(x));` above -- invoking *Undefined Behavior* due to the mismatch in conversion specifier and argument size) and are bewildered by the fact it always returns `sizeof (a_pointer)`. So at times, being a pedant is a good-thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is a *pointer* to the first element in an array. (`x` is not an array.)

As `x` is not `const`, you are free to modify it. `x++` modifies it to point to the *second* element in the array.

When you then attempt to free the dynamically-allocated array (`free(x)`) you are passing `free()` a value that `malloc` *did not give you*. Hence the debugger triggering a break.

Either restore `x` to its prior value before attempting to free it, or use a different pointer variable to play arithmetic and leave `x` alone.

Answer (score -1):

compiling with 'gcc' command line:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled.c" -o "untitled.o"
```

linked with the command line:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -o "untitled" "untitled.o"
```

modified code, with comments

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int* x;
    x = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    // in C,  the memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc)
    // returned type is 'void*' which can be assigned to any pointer
    // so casting just clutters the code and is error prone.

    if (!x)
    {
        perror("sorry met an error");
        // the 'perror' function outputs to 'stderr' the text meaning of 
        // the 'errno' variable plus the text supplied by the parameter.
        // note: in the current scenario 'errno' was set by 'malloc'

        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        // EXIT_FAILURE is defined in stdlib.h'
    }
    
    x[0] = 0;
    x[1] = 1;
    x[2] = 2;
    
    printf("%p\n", (void*)x);
    // %p requires a 'void*' parameter
    
    printf("%d\n", x[0]);
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(x));
    // sizeof returns a 'long unsigned int' value
    // which is printable via '%zu'
    
    x++;
    // this modifies the pointer returned via 'malloc'
    // it does not change where the array is located in memory
    
    printf("%p\n", (void*)x);
    printf("%d\n", x[0]);
    printf("%d\n", x[1]);
    printf("%zu", sizeof(x));
    
    free(x);   
    // the pointer to the array has been changed
    // so this will fail at runtime
    
    return 0;
}
```

with the modified code, the following is the output

```
0x562e604882a0
0
8
0x562e604882a4
1
2
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```